# L2TP ipsec using network-manager-l2tp and strongswan ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, strongswan, l2tp

The VPN works flawlessly on OSX and Windows 10 but no luck with ubuntu

VPN gets connected on ubuntu using 
Phase1 Algorithms : 3des-sha1-modp1024
Phase2 Algorithms : 3des-sha1

And in 10 seconds gets disconnected with the below msgs

```
    xl2tpd[12406]: message_type_avp: message type 6 (Hello)
xl2tpd[12406]: control_finish: message type is Hello(6).  Tunnel is 57299, call is 0.
xl2tpd[12406]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 57299 (got 2, expected 3)
xl2tpd[12406]: handle_packet: bad control packet!
xl2tpd[12406]: network_thread: bad packet
xl2tpd[12406]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 57299 (got 2, expected 3)
xl2tpd[12406]: handle_packet: bad control packet!
xl2tpd[12406]: network_thread: bad packet
xl2tpd[12406]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 57299 (got 2, expected 3)
xl2tpd[12406]: handle_packet: bad control packet!
xl2tpd[12406]: network_thread: bad packet
xl2tpd[12406]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 57299 (got 2, expected 3)
xl2tpd[12406]: handle_packet: bad control packet!
xl2tpd[12406]: network_thread: bad packet
xl2tpd[12406]: Maximum retries exceeded for tunnel 39703.  Closing.
xl2tpd[12406]: Terminating pppd: sending TERM signal to pid 12407
xl2tpd[12406]: Connection 57299 closed to [X.X.X.X], port 1701 (Timeout)
xl2tpd[12406]: message_type_avp: message type 4 (Stop-Control-Connection-Notification)
xl2tpd[12406]: assigned_tunnel_avp: using peer's tunnel 57299
xl2tpd[12406]: result_code_avp: peer closing for reason 1 (General request to clear control connection), error = 0 (Timeout)
xl2tpd[12406]: control_finish: message type is Stop-Control-Connection-Notification(4).  Tunnel is 57299, call is 0.
xl2tpd[12406]: control_finish: Connection closed to [X.X.X.X], port 1701 (Timeout), Local: 39703, Remote: 57299
xl2tpd[12406]: build_fdset: closing down tunnel 39703
xl2tpd[12406]: Can not find tunnel 39703 (refhim=0)
xl2tpd[12406]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 0, tunnel = 39703 Dumping.
xl2tpd[12406]: Can not find tunnel 39703 (refhim=0)
xl2tpd[12406]: network_thread: unable to find call or tunnel to handle packet.  call = 0, tunnel = 39703 Dumping.
nm-l2tp[12257] <info>  Terminated xl2tpd daemon with PID 12406.
xl2tpd[12406]: death_handler: Fatal signal 15 received
Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
** Message: 19:27:49.639: ipsec shut down
nm-l2tp[12257] <warn>  xl2tpd exited with error code 1
Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running
```

Please advice

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Nope :( switched to openVPN

Comment: Is there no one that can answer this?